# How to increase the canvas bit depth to create a higher quality picture in javaScript? and how to increate the canvas size when outputting

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I'm new to HTML5 and JavaScript, and I'm trying to use the canvas element to create a high(ish) quality output image.

1. The current purpose is to allow users to all their own images (jpeg, png, svg). this works like a charm. however when I render the image it's always a 32-bit png. how can I create a higher quality picture using JavaScript(preferably) ?
2. when I output the file, it always seems to keep the same resolution as the canvas, how can I change this using JavaScript(preferably)

Thanks in Advance guys, I looked around for a while but I couldn't find the answer to this :(

Comment: You've asked two questions here.  May be better to get the answer to one, then ask another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well firstly, when you draw the image to the canvas it's not a png quite yet, it's a simple raw bitmap where the canvas API works on as you call it's methods, then it's converted to a png in order for the browser to display it, and that's what you get when you use `toDataURL`. When using `toDataURL` you're able to choose which image format you want the output to be, I think jpeg and bmp are supported along with png. (Don't think of it as a png converted to another format, cause it's not)

And I don't know what exactly do you mean by higher quality by adding more bits to a pixel, you see 32 bits are enough for all RGBA channels to have a true color 8 bits depth giving you *way* more colors than the human eye can see *at once*. I know depending on the lighting and angle in which the user is exposed to your picture his perception of the colors may vary but not the *quality* of it which I'd say only depends on the resolution it has. Anyway the canvas was not designed to work with those deeper colors and honestly that much color information isn't even necessary on any kind of scene you could render on the canvas, that's only relevant for high definition movies and games made by big studios, also, even if you could use deep colors on the canvas it would really depend on the support of the user's videocard and screen which I think the majority of people doesn't have.

If you wish to add information not directly concerned to the color of each pixel but maybe on potencial transformations they could have you better create your own type capable of carrying the `imageData` acceptable by the canvas API, keeping it's 32-bit format, and the additional information on a corresponding array.

And yes, the output image has the same resolution as the canvas do but there are a couple of ways provided for you to resize your final composition. Just do as Simon Sarris said, create an offscreen canvas which resolution is the final resolution you want your image to be, then, you can either:

1. Resize the raster image by calling `drawImage` while providing the `toDataURL` generated image making use of the resizing parameters
2. Redraw your scene there, as Simon said, which will reduce quality loss if your composition contains shapes created through the canvas API and not only image files put together

In case you know the final resolution you want it to be beforehand then just set the width and height of the canvas to it, but the CSS width and height can be set differently in order for your canvas to fit in your webpage as you wish.

Comment: 32-bit RGBA can not show gradual changes realistically. See for example https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3dtGD4

Comment: @Delta "that much color information isn't even necessary on any kind of scene you could render on the canvas" is no longer a valid argument. Perhaps this wasn't so relevant back in 2012, but nowadays there are several cameras (depth, infrared, etc) that could be easily integrated to web apps if canvas supported higher depths.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a larger image with getImageData or toDataURL then you have to:

1. Create an in-memory canvas that is larger than your normal canvas
2. Redraw your entire scene onto your in-memory canvas. You will probably want to call `ctx.scale(theScale, theScale)` on your in-memory context in order to scale your images, but this heavily depends on how they were created in the first place (images? Canvas paths?)
3. Call `getImageData` or `toDataURL` on the in-memory canvas and not your
   normal canvas

By in-memory canvas I mean:

```
var inMem = document.createElement('canvas');
// The larger size
inMem.width = blah;
inMem.height = blah;
```

Comment: So if my scene is created using lots of paths, will it scale up nicely or will they become blurry too?